# How to create method that got generic parameter and return object of that type?

Tags: java, generics

I need to make a method that make a object from byte array. My best try:

```
private static <T> T objectCreate(byte[] bytes, Class<T> clazzType) {
        if (clazzType.isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
            t = (T) new String(bytes);
            return t;
        }
}
```

But here I have a unchecked cast on line `t = (T) new String(bytes);`

Can I do this better?

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the object is not assignable from `String`? Also why do you need the `String` to create the object based on the array?

Comment: The unchecked cast in these cases is unavoidable, just surpress the warning.

Comment: I am making protocol for Kafka deserialization. So, when I am reading from byte stream I say:"I have one String to read now, read that String and make String object". I will cover all possibilities of objects in this method and throw exception if some Object that is not covered appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Class.cast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-):

```
t = clazzType.cast(new String(bytes));
```

This is logical to use since you are relying on `Class` methods for type checking. However it is just a stylistic difference; though it does not emit a warning, it is still an unchecked operation in its own sense.